# How to set spaces between tab bar using margin?

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS. I am designing a tab bar menu. I am using a unordered list `<ul>` for tabs. I wrote a css for that tab. I need to add desired space between each tab.

My code is:

```css
 #tab-menu li a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #ffffff;
 }
 .button {
   background: #FEFEFE;
   background: rgba(254, 254, 254, 1);
   border-radius: 11px;
   -moz-border-radius: 11px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 11px;
 }
 #tab-menu ul li {
   list-style: none;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   width: 90px;
   height: 90px;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 50px;
   /* Here I need to add equal spaces between each tab. */
   border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
   background: #D9DADA;
   background: rgba(217, 218, 218, 1);
   border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 0px;
   -moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 0px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 0px;
 }
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#bfbfbf">
  <div id="tab-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="01.svg" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="01.svg" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="01.svg" />/a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="01.svg" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="01.svg" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="01.svg" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="01.svg" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="01.svg" />
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>

  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Add ticket" />
</body>
```

Can someone help me code?

Comment: use margins to have some space.

Comment: But how could I use it? Can you please brief it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS

```
#tab-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.button {
  background: #FEFEFE;
  background: rgba(254, 254, 254, 1);
  border-radius: 11px;
  -moz-border-radius: 11px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 11px;
}
#tab-menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-right: 15px;//this adds space
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
  background: #D9DADA;
  background: rgba(217, 218, 218, 1);
  border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 0px;
}
```